# Open static google map in Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, fancybox

I am trying to load a static google map into a fancybox/lightbox when clicking on a link. 
My code is

```
<a href="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
 zoom=13&size=400x400&markers=color:blue|32,50&sensor=true"><img src="icon.png" /></a>
```

But it won't show, the iframe stays empty. I guess it's because the map is supposed to be loaded as the src of an IMG element, right?

Any idea how to solve this issue?

An alternative would be to open a normal google map in theviframe but then it always shows two markers, one at the location and one "best guess" by google - is there a way to remove that "best guess" marker? See http://blog.felixsalomon.net for an example, click on the little map icon next to the title of the first post.

Thanks!

Comment: what version of fancybox? If using fancybox v2.x check http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples (extended functionality --> media helper) ... also make sure you include the media js file

Comment: I am using 1.3.4 and yes I know these examples but those are not static google maps. See original post for link to my page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static maps (using Google [Static Map API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)) can be rendered as regular images.

Since your link :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&size=400x400&markers=color:blue|32,50&sensor=true"><img src="icon.png" /></a>
```

... doesn't tell fancybox that this is an `image` (because it doesn't have an image extension), you have to force the `type` of content fancybox needs to handle like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    "type":"image"
});
```

**Notice** that I added `class="fancybox"` to the anchor so fancybox can be bound to that selector.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eeZFb/)** (using fancybox v1.3.4)

**EDIT** : Since you are using a fancybox WP plugin, alternatively you can add the `image` extension to the anchor at the end of the URL, adding `&filename=image.jpg` for instance ... so your full URL will look like :

```
href="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&size=400x400&markers=color:blue|32,50&sensor=true&filename=image.jpg"
```

If you do this, you don't have to edit the Easyfancybox script. Check **[updated JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eeZFb/3/)**

Comment: I actually have the class fancybox and iframe added to the anchor but lost it during copy and paste ... one question: where do I add the jQuery code? I'm actually running Wordpress using the Easyfancybox plugin and am not very familiar with the setup of fancybox....

Comment: Hmm, getting a "The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later." error. See blog.felixsalomon.net. I must be missing something I guess?

Comment: Nope it's working, forgot the "size=" parameter. Do you happen to know how I can make the fancybox singular, i.e. it doesn't show the arrows to jump to the next map/image??

Comment: @Dreamingof8a just remove the `rel` attribute from the element you want out of the gallery

Comment: Unfortunately there is no rel attribute. The links look like  echo <a class="geotagged fancybox iframe" title="xx" href="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&size=300x300&markers=color:blue|10,10'&sensor=true&filename=image.jpg"><img src="/images/geotagged.png" alt="alt" /></a> yet they are still grouped together ...

Comment: I can see `rel="gallery"` within the `<a>` tag (after the `href` attribute) ... just after where you added `&amp;filename=image.jpg`

Comment: `<a class="geotagged fancybox iframe" title="Posted near Buenos Aires, Argentina" href="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&amp;size=300x300&amp;markers=color:blue|-34.586994,-58.423951&amp;sensor=true&amp;filename=image.jpg" rel="gallery"><img src="http://blog.felixsalomon.net/wp-content/themes/dusk-to-dawn/images/geotagged.png" alt="Posted near Buenos Aires, Argentina"></a>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24805/discussion-between-dreamingof8a-and-jfk)